# Have same thing when checking what the function string.match return in Lua

Tags: string, lua

I'm new in lua and in this forum. I'm testing if a string have only a alphanumeric characters.

For this I use string.match function and I test what the function return.

Here my code:

```
function ReadFistMacAddressFile (_FilePath)

    local file = open(_FilePath, "rb") -- r read mode and b binary mode
    if not file then
        file:close()
        appli.Test_failed("Can't open the file".. _FilePath .. ".\n\n Verify the path.")
        return nil
    end
    
    print("------------------------")
    print("-------------------------")
    local size = sizeFile (file)
    print("     size = " .. size)
    print("")
    print("")
    if size == 0 then
        file:close()
        appli.Test_failed("Mac Adress file's empty")
        return nil
    end
        
    
    local lignes = ReadLine (file, 1)
    print("     lignes = " .. lignes)
    print("")
    print("")
    
    local NoneAlphaNumericFind = nil 
    NoneAlphaNumericFind = string.match(lignes,"[^%w]")
    print("     NoneAlphaNumericFind = " .. NoneAlphaNumericFind)
    print("")
    print("")
    
    if NoneAlphaNumericFind == nil or NoneAlphaNumericFind == '' then
        file:close()
        return lignes
    else
        file:close()
        appli.Test_failed("Mac adress contain the characteres: ".. NoneAlphaNumericFind)    
        return nil 
    end
    
end
```

I open the mac adress file, read the first line and test if the string have only alphanumeric characters

The problem that I have is I go to else condition in any case. I saw in lua docs that string.match return nil if it doesn't find the pattern, so i don't undestantd why it doesn't work.

[Here were there is only alaphanumeric characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rM8kK.png)

[Here were there is a none alaphanumeric characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlLgO.png)

I thank you in advance for your help.

I've tried every solution that I saw in this forum and none work.

Comment: How `ReadLine` is implemented?  Does it return line terminator (LF) which is of course a non-alphanumeric char?

Answer (score 0):

Your file is opened as binary (in `rb` mode), so `CRLF` line terminator is not converted to `LF`.
Only `LF` is auto-removed by Lua `file:lines()` and `file:read()` functions.
So, non-alphanumeric `CR` char in still in the line returned, it always matches `[^%w]` pattern.

BTW, Lua has `%x` pattern to match a hexadecimal digit.
You can use `[^%x]` or simply `%X` pattern to find a char which is not from the set `0-9A-Fa-f`

Comment: Thank you for your response. 

For your solution, I've already tried to use the pattern [^%x] but I have the same problem.

Comment: Replace `"rb"` with `"r"`